# C# Numeric UpDown with auto 'add/subtract' function

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a `NumericUpDown` control, and I want the value inside a seperate textbox to decrease or increase depending on which input the user inputes (up or down)

What event or code do I use to accomplish this?
I tried this but got an error while running

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
  int UpDownNum;
  int NumBank;
  int TV = 0
  private void UpDown1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UpDownNum = (Convert.ToInt32(UpDown1));
        NumBank = (Convert.ToInt32(NumTextbox.Text));

        TV = NumBank - UpDownNum;
        NumTextbox.Text = (Convert.ToString(TV));
```

Am I doing the wrong event? or is it some other problem?

Comment: You need to look at the `UpDown1.Value` property - you are currently trying to convert the Control itself to a number. So your line becomes `UpDownNum = Convert.ToInt32(UpDown1.Value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by casting the `NumericUpdown` control to an integer. That doesn't work. You need to use the [`NumericUpdown.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.

I assume that it's the  [`ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx) event that you're looking for:

```
private decimal oldValue = 0;

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericUpDown UpDown1 = (NumericUpDown)sender;
    decimal diff = UpDown1.Value - oldValue;
    oldValue = UpDown1.Value;
    int numBank = int.Parse(NumTextBox.Text);
    decimal newValue = numBank + diff;
    NumTextBox.Text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

**Edit**:

The only  way i know to get the difference between the old and the new value of a `NumericUpDown` value is to save the old value manually(for example in a member variable) and change it in ValueChanged after you've calculated  the difference (see edited code above).

Comment: In the line `int newValue = numBank - updown1.Value` I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @JoeFredy: Sorry, should have tested it. Edited my answer accodingly.

Comment: @JoeFredy `NumericUpdown.Value` is a decimal according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx).

Comment: Ok, that works. but now clicking the UpDown either up or down subtracts from the textbox, also I want to make it so when you change the UpDown by 1, it changes the textbox by 1 (how it is now it changes it bye whats in the UpDown)
So I changed it to `decimal newValue = numBank -1

Comment: Can I get two different events for each up/down action?

Comment: @JoeFredy No, but if you store the previous value you can check the current value against that.

Comment: @JoeFredy: Yes, that's the only way i know. Save the old value manually(for example in a member variable) and change it in ValueChanged after you've calculated  the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You mast to catch [`NumericUpDown.ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx) event, and get [`NumericUpDown.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
private void NumericUpDown1ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var num = ((NumericUpDown) sender).Value;
    newTextBox.Text = num.ToString();
}
```